# Why is a field in an auto-generated class serialized into an element when defined as an attribute in the XSD?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, xsd.exe, auto-generate

I'm trying to expose a fairly complex object as XML through a REST API (using WCF).

However, the object is defined by an XSD file so I've generated classes using the xsd.exe tool. The problem is that it seems that when my object is serialized to XML, an attribute (defined in the xsd) is serialized into an element. And I don't get why. Currently, I'm assuming that my xsd somehow allows that, but I can't tell why.
I don't do any custom serialization, I let the framework handle it.

**Can someone explain why this is happening and how do I control the behavior?**

Here the part from the xsd containing the element and attribute.
**Edit:** the attribute in question is *version*

```
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://some.namespace.com/" xmlns="http://someothernamespace.com/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://someothernamespace.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:include schemaLocation="JobPositionPosting.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="Envelope">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Sender" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="TransactInfo" />
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Packet" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute fixed="0.52" name="version" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

And here's the generated code.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "<removed>")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://somenamespace.com", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Envelope
{

    /// <remarks/>
    public Sender Sender;

    /// <remarks/>
    public TransactInfo TransactInfo;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Packet")]
    public Packet[] Packet;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("version")]
    public string version;

    public Envelope()
    {
        this.version = "0.52";
    }
}
```

And here's the xml returned from the REST service, i.e. the serialized object.

```
<!-- (the rest o the xml is left out on purpose) -->
<Envelope>
    <senderField i:nil="true"/>
    <transactInfoField i:nil="true"/>
    <versionField>0.52</versionField>
</Envelope>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`xsd.exe` produces classes to be used by [`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer), while your REST-service is using some variant of [`System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer).

For `DataContractSerializer`, you should use [`svcutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) instead.

```
svcutil.exe /help
svcutil.exe schema.xsd /dconly
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it seems like the svcutil can't handle my xsd. Whatever options I tried, it tells me it cannot load data from the assembly (which indicates it doesn't know how to handle the xsd).

Instead, I tried modifying the generated classes to be able to use the XmlSerializer instead. I'm having a few problems, but I hope to solve those very soon.

Comment: @Anton It seems `svcutil.exe` does not support XML attributes, especially the `use="required"` setting. Only `xsd.exe` allows that. To use `XmlSerializer` with WCF, you can specify the [`XmlSerializerFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute.aspx) attribute on the class.