# XmlSerializer : formatting tags

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I serialize simply Person which has Items as collection using .NET  XmlSerializer;

```
class Item
{
   Name
   Price
}

class Person
{
   Name
   List Items<Item>
}
```

Everthing fine...I use XmlWriterSettings to indent my xml file. The output is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <name>TestName</name>
  <Items>
    <Item>
      <name>one</name>
      <price>0</price>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <name>two</name>
      <price>1</price>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</Viewport>
```

But what I want is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <name>TestName</name>
  <Items>
     <Item name="one" price="0" />
     <Item name="two" price="1" />
  </Items>
</Viewport>
```

Shortly instead of

```
<Item>
      <name>one</name>
      <price>0</price>
 </Item>
```

I want to write xml as

```
<Item name="one" price="0" />
```

How can i do it in .NET(C#) ?

Comment: This question is similar to this one (i.e. attribute vs. element behavior when serializing): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449564/why-is-a-field-in-an-auto-generated-class-serialized-into-an-element-when-define

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorate your `Name` & `Price` properties with `XmlAttribute`

Answer (score 2):

```
class Item
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("name")]
    string Name;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("price")]
    string Price;
}
```